# Date Intervals Doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am trying to get data by week, month and year.

I store date YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.

What I am doing is below;

**Fetch one week old data;**

```
query + AND WEEK(date) = WEEK(CURDATE())
```

**Fetch a month old data;**

```
query + AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE())
```

The thing is I couldnt be able to get the data correct. For instance when I want to get week old data, I am gettin a year old one too.

Is there any other query that I could use? I have tried `DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 30 DAY`. It works but very slow.

Thanks!

Comment: What data type is the date field? Do you have an index on that field?

Comment: The type is text, Indexing dates as date(50) BTREE

Comment: Change it to `datetime`

Comment: I did now, but having the same issue :(

Comment: You have to filter on the year also or you will get that week for all previous and future years also.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the problem is that the `WEEK` function returns the week of the year. So, Jan 1st 2017 might be week 1 (also might be week 53 of the previous year depending on the day of the week and how MySQL handles it). But then, Jan 1st of 2016 is also week 1 - just for a different year.

Trying changing it to:

```
query + AND WEEK(date) = WEEK(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

Also, if you're storing this as a string then definitely change it to a `DATETIME`

Comment: or use YEARWEEK()

Comment: Thank you this works greately too. Would you suggest me using the function you mentioned, or `DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY`. Would there be any significant difference?

Comment: Yes, those two things are different. One will be the period of time for the past 7 days (so, a rolling week). The one that I have posted will be for a given week based on when your week boundary is set. So, Monday - Sunday for example. If you reported on the current week on Wednesday it would be Mon-Wed.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE ...
  AND date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
  AND date  < CURDATE()
```

Gives you the 7 days ending with yesterday.  Use other techniques to get a particular month or week.

This technique is also much faster for large tables with a suitable index.  Hiding `date` inside a function, such as `WEEK()` prevents the use of an index.